# Url Redirection Help Required

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress and Woocommerce. It is generating these ridiculously long URLs:

http://digital-dev.co.uk/a3m/shop/products/portable-stands/portable-counters/

I would like to alter it so that it reads like this:

http://digital-dev.co.uk/a3m/portable-stands/portable-counters/

I cannot seem to get a redirection working correctly for this. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused! Do you want to redirect somewhere? or are you trying to change the slug?

Comment: I would like to change the slug by rewriting out 'shop/products' and leaving the following in place.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. Have you edited the permalink structure in WordPress settings?

Here's a guide that contains information on how to edit the permalink structure:  http://edenfried.com/things-you-should-do-after-installing-wordpress/#tab-con-4

Comment: Yes I have and Wordpress does not allow this change through the back end. It is not a change which Wordpress or Woocommerce wish to happen due to duplicate content concerns when you dont know what you are doing.